# How to color the top 20 nodes over the rest of the nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Does anyone know how to color the top 20 nodes over the rest of the nodes in NetworkX?
I would like to color the top 20 nodes with green and the rest with gray.
However, the output only shows gray because the green nodes were under the gray nodes.
Would it be possible to make those green nodes over the gray nodes?

In addition, would it be possible to show the top 20 green nodes to be sized in 20 and the rest of gray nodes to be sized in 10? Currently, all the nodes are sized in 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list(string.ascii_uppercase),
                   'PageRank': np.random.randint(10, 100, len(string.ascii_uppercase))})

top_5_lst = df.sort_values('PageRank')['ID'].head(5).tolist()
not_top_5_lst = df.loc[~df['ID'].isin(top_5_lst), 'ID'].tolist()

edges = pd.DataFrame({'from': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), 1000),
                      'to': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), 1000)})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='from', target='to')
```

To do what you expect, you have to control manually the graph drawing especially for z-order. You can do:

```
# Compute positions
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Draw nodes not in top5
pc1 = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=not_top_5_lst,
                             node_color='gray', node_size=10)

# Draw top5 nodes
pc2 = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=top_5_lst, 
                             node_color='#00D992', node_size=20)
pc2.zorder = 3  # set z-order to 3 (2 by default for gray nodes)

# Draw edges
lc = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image: NetworkX graph]

Comment: I was writing an answer to this but I like yours a lot better

Comment: Thank you, @corralien.  

When I tried to visualize the network diagram using the list variable, I received following error message: 
pc1 = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist!=top_20_lst,
                             node_color='gray', node_size=10) --> name 'nodelist' is not defined

When I commented out the pc1 and just draw the pc2, the script ran successfully: pc2 = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=top_20_lst, 
                             node_color='#00D992', node_size=20)

Do you know why?

Comment: Don't use `top_20_lst` anymore. Use `rank` and `rank[:20]` to get top20 and `range[20:]` to get other nodes. You have to build 2 lists not only one (`top_20_lst)`

Comment: Would it be possible to use top_20_lst instead?  The list of top 20 nodes would be pre-defined unfortunately.

Comment: @knozawa. I updated my answer. Please can you kindly check it? I use the `top_X_lst` to build another list `not_top_X_lst`. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thank you, @Corralien.  That makes sense.  This is minor, but do you know if it's possible to remove the outside container (square box)?

Comment: `plt.axis('off')`

Answer (score 3):

At the request of @Corralien, I'll try to add something on.
If you're ok using a non networkx package, you can also do what you're asking to do with Plotly, which gives the added benefit of interactivity. You can follow a similar example [here](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/)

Setup the exact same MRE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list(string.ascii_uppercase),
                   'PageRank': np.random.randint(10, 100, len(string.ascii_uppercase))})

top_5_lst = df.sort_values('PageRank')['ID'].head(5).tolist()
not_top_5_lst = df.loc[~df['ID'].isin(top_5_lst), 'ID'].tolist()

edges = pd.DataFrame({'from': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), 1000),
                      'to': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), 1000)})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='from', target='to')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

Set page rank as an attribute for nodes. We'll use this to add a tooltip

```
rank_dict = dict(zip(df.ID, df.PageRank))
for entry in rank_dict:
    rank_dict[entry] = {'Page Rank': rank_dict[entry]}
    
nx.set_node_attributes(G, rank_dict)
```

Set edges:

```
edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = pos[edge[0]]
    x1, y1 = pos[edge[1]]
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')
```

Set up one trace each for the top 5 nodes by page rank and rest of nodes.

```
# Not Top 5 Nodes
g1_node_x = []
g1_node_y = []
g1_texts = []
# Top 5 Nodes
g2_node_x = []
g2_node_y = []
g2_texts = []
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = pos[node]
    if node in not_top_5_lst:
        g1_node_x.append(x)
        g1_node_y.append(y)
        g1_texts.append('Page Rank: '+str(G.nodes[node]['Page Rank']))
    else:
        g2_node_x.append(x)
        g2_node_y.append(y)
        g2_texts.append('Page Rank: '+str(G.nodes[node]['Page Rank']))

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=g1_node_x, y=g1_node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        color='grey',
        size=10,
        line_width=2))

node_trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=g2_node_x, y=g2_node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        color='green',
        size=20,
        line_width=2))

node_trace.text = g1_texts
node_trace2.text = g2_texts
```

Finally, create your plotly figure and add in each trace. Then update your layout as desired. Plotly orders elements by the order they were added to the trace so as long as the top element nodes are plotted *after* the bottom element nodes, they will appear in front

```
fig = go.Figure(edge_trace)
fig = fig.add_trace(node_trace)
fig = fig.add_trace(node_trace2)

fig = fig.update_layout(titlefont_size=16,
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False)

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice work and good explanation. There is only one thing I don't understand (because I don't know Plotly objects): why you have to do `edge_x.append(None)` and `edge_y.append(None)`? Can you explain me? +1 for your work!

Comment: It's kind of an odd syntax trick that allows you to treat the edges as disconnected from each other so that you can plot them without a for loop. The Plotly documentation on plotting lines on maps notes `If you can relinquish setting individual line styles (e.g. opacity), you can put multiple paths into one trace. This makes the map render faster and reduces the script execution time and memory consumption.

Use None between path coordinates to create a break in the otherwise connected paths.`

https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/